# Adding reduction potentials?

Tags: thermodynamics, electrochemistry, redox

Will it be wrong to add reduction potentials of two intermediate reactions to get reduction potential of net reaction(just like as we do in adding enthalpies and applying Hess's law)?

What is the basic error? What should be the thinking process to avoid these kind of errors in chemistry?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate reduction potentials from given standard potentials for cobalt?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/9454/how-to-calculate-reduction-potentials-from-given-standard-potentials-for-cobalt)

Comment: @Mithoron       The answer at there does not explain my question properly

Comment: @JM97 please [edit] your question to explain how.

Comment: Well, $\Delta G=-nFE$, so as long as you keep count of your electrons (n) properly, there are no reasons to worry.

Comment: @IvanNeretin but E is independent of number of electrons

Comment: Then $\Delta G$ is.

Comment: @IvanNeretin That's an extensive property

Comment: That's right. So what?

Comment: @IvanNeretin why can't we add E at each stet to get final E just like we add H(Hess law)

Comment: Yes we can. Just keep in mind the number of electrons, because it is important. Number of electrons times potential is energy. The energy must be conserved, that's the law. There is no law for conservation of potential, though.