# Calculating the standard reduction potential for the oxidation of water

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, electrochemistry, redox, water

I was working with Latimer and Frost diagrams for oxygen when I came across what seems to me a contradiction.

From the Latimer diagram for oxygen below, we know the standard reduction potential for the reduction of $\ce{O2}$ to $\ce{H2O2}$ and the standard reduction potential for the reduction of $\ce{H2O2}$ to $\ce{H2O}$, as represented in the following chemical equations:

$$\ce{O2} \overset{+0.70}{\longrightarrow} \ce{H2O2} \overset{+1.76}{\longrightarrow} \ce{H2O}$$

$$\begin{align}
\ce{2H+ (aq) + 2e- + H2O2 (aq) &-> 2H2O (l)} & E^\circ &= \pu{+1.76 V} \\
\ce{O2 (g) + 2H+ (aq) + 2e- &-> H2O2 (aq)} & E^\circ &= \pu{+0.70 V} \\
\end{align}$$

If we add these two reduction chemical equations, we can find the standard reduction potential for the reduction of $\ce{O2}$ to $\ce{H2O2}$, which would be $\pu{+2.46 V}$ according to the aformentioned reduction potentials and chemical equations.

The reduction of $\ce{O2}$ to $\ce{H2O}$ is the reverse reaction of the oxidation of water:

$$\ce{2H2O(l) -> O2(g) + 4H+(aq) + 4e-}\qquad E^\circ = \pu{-1.23 V}$$

Why does the standard reduction potential for the oxidation of water calculated from the Latimer diagram differ from the value reported in the table of standard reduction potentials? **More specifically, why is the value calculated from the Latimer diagram double of that reported in the table?** I checked my work multiple times and do not understand why this occurs, but I might have still made a silly mistake.

**References**
Shriver, D. F., Weller, M. T., Overton, T., Rourke, J., & Armstrong, F. A. (2014). *Inorganic chemistry 6th Edition*.

Comment: Related (pretty much the same thing, tbh): [Deriving a reduction potential from two other reduction potentials](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/9454/16683)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Hess’ law, we expect the Gibbs energy change $\Delta G$ of the two partial reactions to add up to the total Gibbs energy change:

$$\Delta G_1+\Delta G_2=\Delta G_3$$

For an electrochemical reaction, the change in Gibbs energy corresponds to an electrochemical potential $E$ according to

$$\Delta G = -zFE$$

where
$F$ is the Faraday constant and
$z$ is the number of electrons transferred.

Since for the two partial reactions the number of electrons is $z_1=z_2=2$, but for the total reaction $z_3=4$, we expect:

$$\begin{align}\Delta G_1+\Delta G_2&=\Delta G_3\\
z_1E_1+z_2E_2&=z_3E_3\\
2\times0.695\ \mathrm V+2\times1.763\ \mathrm V&=4\times1.229\ \mathrm V
\end{align}$$